# Javascript or PHP code that checks if user has liked a post then send an option to unlike to that specific post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I recently tried to say if the username and postid is in the database then echo this button that tells you to unlike. But, that came out true for all post even if the user didn't like that post. I was wondering if there's a way to work around that with a certain javascript or php code. 
For PHP I have everything in a while loop so that everything is all in one place and each time a user post something, it's all there. What I tried to say is if the username is equal to the username in the `likes` table then give me the option to echo out a unlike button. Like I mentioned before, it came out true for every post. `(($_SESSION['username']) ==  $lrow['username'])`. **I know that my current code is unsafe, this is just for testing and I need some help with this one problem. I also apperciate all the support from my previous questions as I am still learning.**

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo    '<div class="social-img hide-750">';
        echo    '<div class="social-content">';
        echo    '<a href="../profiles/uploads/'.$row["images"].'"  data-fancybox="quote">';
        echo     ' <img src="../profiles/uploads/'.$row["images"].'">';
        echo     ' </a>';
        echo     ' <a href="'.$row['username'].'"><p>Uploaded by: '.$row["username"].'</p></a>';
        $usernames = $_SESSION['username'];
        $rresult = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM likes WHERE  username='$usernames'");
        $lrow = mysqli_fetch_array($rresult);


        if (($_SESSION['username']) ==  $lrow['username']) {
            // user has already liked post
            echo'<div data-id="'.$row['id'].'" class="icon-appear">
                <span  class="icon"><i style="color: #FFD700;" class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
                <div class="border"><span></span></div>
                <div class="satellite">
                <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                </div>
                <span class="likes_count">'.$row['likes'].'</span>
                </div>';
                echo'<div data-id="'.$row['id'].'" class="icon-wrapper hide">
                <span  class="icon"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
                <div class="border"><span></span></div>
                <div class="satellite">
                <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                </div>
                <span class="likes_count">'.$row['likes'].'</span>
                </div>';

        } else {
            // user has not liked quote
        if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        echo'<div data-id="'.$row['id'].'" class="icon-wrapper">
                <span  class="icon"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
                <div class="border"><span></span></div>
                <div class="satellite">
                <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                </div>
                <span class="likes_count">'.$row['likes'].'</span>
                </div>';
                echo'<div data-id="'.$row['id'].'" class="icon-appear hide">
                <span  class="icon"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
                <div class="border"><span></span></div>
                <div class="satellite">
                <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                </div>
                <span class="likes_count">'.$row['likes'].'</span>
                </div>';

        }
        }
        if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        echo'<a style="text-decoration: none; color: gray;"  href="#signup" data-toggle="modal"><div  class="fake-wrapper">
                <span  class="icon"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
                <div class="border"><span></span></div>
                <div class="satellite">
                <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                </div>
                <span class="likes_count">'.$row['likes'].'</span>
                </div></a>';
        }
```

Here is the javascript that sends a post to a php code and tells the code to 'like' or 'unlike'

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // when the user clicks on like
    $('.icon-wrapper').on('click', function(){
        var postid = $(this).data('id');
            $post = $(this);

        $.ajax({

            url: 'user_profiles.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'liked': 1,
                'postid': postid
            },

            success: function(response){
                $post.parent().find('span.likes_count').text(response);

                $post.addClass('hide');
                $post.siblings().removeClass('hide');
                $post.siblings().addClass('anim');
                $post.removeClass('anim');


            }
        });
    });


// when the user clicks on unlike
    $('.icon-appear').on('click', function(){
        var postid = $(this).data('id');
        $post = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'user_profiles.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'unliked': 1,
                'postid': postid
            },
            success: function(response){
                $post.parent().find('span.likes_count').text(response);
                $post.siblings().removeClass('anim');
                $post.addClass('anim');
                $post.addClass('hide');
                $post.siblings().removeClass('hide');

            }
        });
    });
});
```

If the person clicks `icon-wrapper` it should 'like' and if clicked again it should hide `icon-wrapper` and 'unlike'.

Comment: I _think_ you need only `SELECT * FROM likes` instead of `SELECT * FROM likes WHERE  username='$usernames'`

Comment: Ok now everything is echoing the option to signup @SearchAndResQ

Comment: I'm sorry! @SearchAndResQ You were right! I also had to change my username structure in the database to user id! haha. Make sure you post your answer so that others can see it too!